# How to check if there are two (or more) forward slashes in a string of an Array item with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have below response from a graphql query:

```js
"menu": [{
    "url": ""
  },
  {
    "url": "/"
  },
  {
    "url": "/item/child-item"
  }
]
```

I need a Boolean variable and check if there is an item in the Array with two (or more) forward slashes `/`. So it has a child-item in the path like `"/item/child-item"`

```
const hasChild = data.menu.map((item) => item.url.includes('// What to do here?'));
```

Comment: Includes `//` or starts with `//`?

Comment: Or includes two `/` but not necessarily together? (Your third example.) With a question like this, it's always useful to show examples that match and don't match and to say specifically which are which.

Comment: yeah sorry, like the third example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method returns an array, as you're after a boolean, you need to use something different. The [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method can instead be used, which will return `true` as soon as the callback you pass it returns `true`. The `.some()` will iterate through all of your objects within your array until your callback returns `true`. You can use the [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to remove any occurrences of characters that are not `/` and grab the length to check if it appears two or more:

```js
const hasChild = data.menu.some(menuItem => menuItem.url.replace(/[^/]/g, '').length >= 2);
```

See runnable example below:

```js
const data = {
  "menu": [{
      "url": ""
    },
    {
      "url": "/"
    },
    {
      "url": "/item/child-item"
    }
  ]
};

const hasChild = data.menu.some(menuItem => menuItem.url.replace(/[^/]/g, '').length >= 2);
console.log(hasChild); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). `map()` is when you want to transform an array into another using a function.

You need [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which returns true if any one of the array items fulfills a condition.

You can use that along with [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to count the number of occurences of a particular character in the string.

```js
const data = { "menu": [
      {
        "url": ""
      },
      {
        "url": "/"
      },
      {
        "url": "/item/child-item"
      }
    ] }

const hasChild = data.menu.some((item) => item.url.split('/').length - 1 > 1);

console.log(hasChild);
```

In the above code with `split()`,
`/a/b/c` becomes the array ['','a','b','c']. So you alway get the number of `/` + 1.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you say `replace()` is preferable because of the extra space my code uses?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#some` and as for the test, you can split the `url` by `/` and if the resulting array has more than 2 elements, then there are at least two `/` in the string.

```js
const input = {"menu": [ { "url": "" }, { "url": "/" }, { "url": "/item/child-item" } ] },

      output = input.menu.some(({url}) => url.split("/").length > 2);
      
console.log( output );
```